# Entity Framework code first not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am new to MVC. i create the sample project. i am trying to add the controller using the template with scaffolding options.
it shows the Entity framework code first is not available.

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the error you're getting?

[image]

Is your model in the same project?   If so, cleaning and building should fix the issue and allow you to scaffold your controller.

If not, can you post more detail about what you're getting?  Maybe a screenshot of where you're having the issue?